# Match any character, including special characters using the Match function

Tags: go, glob

I have a relatively weird file names,
but the glob function doesn't seem to pick them up using usual wildcards:

```
fmt.Println(filepath.Match("/home/catch/*.xml", "/home/catch/{foo/x/y}.xml"))
```

so, I want to match xml files in the catch folders, and they might have special characters in their name, like `{path1/path2}.xml`

Sadly, the * wildcard won't match that since I assume slashes and maybe curly braces are considered as non-separator characters?

Comment: Have you tried using `WalkDir` and/or `WalkFunc` to iterate through all the files instead? If there are a lot of lookups, you could build a map of all the files in the filder and match against that map.

Comment: File names can't contain `/` as that is a reserved character for file path separator on unix systems. Windows doesn't allow it either for this reason.

Comment: Do you really intended to match file named "y" located in a directory named "x" which itself is located in a ditectory named "foo" or the file really contains curly braces and slashes? If it's the latter, as @icza said, a slash is basically the only character forbidden to occur in a filename on a Unix system (except, maybe also for a NUL byte, though I'm not sure), so you just cannot have a file whose "bare" name—not a component of its _path_name—contains a slash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Linux and with this pattern Match is returning true . So files like that `{path1/path2}.xml` (although it is not common), it is possible to match them.

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(filepath.Match("/home/catch/*\\/*", "/home/catch/{path1/path2}.xml"))
}
```

**Output**

```
true <nil>
```

But on Windows, escaping is disabled. Instead, `\\` is treated as path separator, so it will not work.

```
"/home/catch/*\\/*"
```

You can read it in the documentation

```
pattern:
{ term }
term:
'*'         matches any sequence of non-Separator characters
'?'         matches any single non-Separator character
'[' [ '^' ] { character-range } ']'
            character class (must be non-empty)
c           matches character c (c != '*', '?', '\\', '[')
'\\' c      matches character c

character-range:
c           matches character c (c != '\\', '-', ']')
'\\' c      matches character c
lo '-' hi   matches character c for lo <= c <= hi

Match requires pattern to match all of name, not just a substring. The only possible returned error is ErrBadPattern, when pattern is malformed.

On Windows, escaping is disabled. Instead, '\\' is treated as path separator.
```

https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Match

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).